# Creating A Temporary File in Php

Tags: php

I was wondering if it's possible to create a temporary page with a php script. Basically what I am wanting to do is have a file at example.com/example/button.php that will access a php script, and create text on say example.com/example/temppage.php. I simply only need it to say "shutdown" for 30 seconds on the temppage, and then it can go back to being blank.

Is this Possible? Thanks!

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/spltempfileobject and http://php.net/tmpfile

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: I am wondering if your idea for a temporary file is based upon a requirement or if you are just unfamiliar with php and its ability to generate dynamic content. Do you NEED to create a temporary file on the server?

Answer (score 2):

There actually is: [click!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php)

Or if you to lazy to click :D

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp); // this removes the file
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, however I need a tempfile with a specific name that is deleted after 30 seconds.. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`tmpfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php)

```
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp); // this removes the file
?>
```