# Generating temporary PDF via .exe or .NET from PHP

Tags: php, .net, com, pdf-generation, temporary-files

### In Short...

I have an ASP.NET script that generates a PDF based on parameters passed to it. Firstly, I need to be able to call this script from PHP, and secondly, I need to ensure that the file is not stored once it is sent to the browser.

### Calling the Script

So my first question is, how can I execute a `.NET` application that requires `DLL's` from PHP? I read something about PHP's `Component Object Model`, but I am a little unsure as to what this is and how it works (I have read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.com.php)). Alternatively, would it be better to compile this script into an `.exe` and call it through that?

Furthermore, is it possible to pass parameters to an `.exe` when calling it via PHP?

### Sending the file without Storing it

Once the file has been generated (either via `.NET` or via an `.exe`), I would like to send it to the browser without storing it on the server. I have looked at the following threads:

1. [Creating A Temporary File in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650695/creating-a-temporary-file-in-php)
2. [Create temporary file and auto removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779205/create-temporary-file-and-auto-removed)

The above threads may contain the correct answer, but I wasn't sure whether it was possible to send a PDF using any of these methods...

### To Conclude

I would like to write a script that achieves the following:

1. Calls a script (either a `.NET` application or an `.exe`), with parameters!
2. Outputs the resulting contents (a PDF) to the browser without storing it on the server

I am not asking anybody to write this script for me, I simply would like some pointers to allow me to write this myself :-)

***There is no point in storing these PDF's on the server as they will rarely be the same***

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your questions....

=>. **So my first question is, how can I execute a .NET application that requires DLL's from PHP?**

Sure, you must create a COM Object to interact with it. In the same page you write there's an example for it like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) one for openning a com object for a word interaction....

```
<?php
// starting word
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
echo "Loaded Word, version {$word->Version}\n";

//bring it to front
$word->Visible = 1;

//open an empty document
$word->Documents->Add();

//do some weird stuff
$word->Selection->TypeText("This is a test...");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("Useless test.doc");

//closing word
$word->Quit();

//free the object
$word = null;
?>
```

=> **Calls a script (either a .NET application or an .exe), with parameters!**

You must have the cli for php in an accesible route to call it with like a console with parameters. You'll have them in the argv array from PHP.

=> **Outputs the resulting contents (a PDF) to the browser without storing it on the server**

Send the correct header to the browser type:application/pdf and it will open what you describe. Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679756/show-a-pdf-files-in-users-browser-via-php-perl)

The code :

```
    <?php
$file='/files/the.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the.pdf"');
@readfile($file);
?>
```

Well you get the point... :)

Comment: Sounds promising, I will give it a go and come back to you. In the meantime, how do I run a .NET script instead of loading a specific application as you have suggested?

Comment: Edited... hope this get you a first approach to the solution.

Comment: Awesome, will have a play around and come back to you. Thanks for your help so far. +1 :-)